# Speeding up the calculation of a rolling mean/std within a grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, function, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with three columns that represent a group, time, and a value. I want to calculate rolling means, standard deviation, etc. within each group. Right now I define a function and use apply. However this is extremely slow on very large data sets. Below is the function.

```
def GetRollingMetrics(x, cols, windows, suffix):
    for col in cols:
        for win in windows:
            x[col + '_' + str(win) + 'D' + '_mean' + '_' + suffix] = x.shift(1).rolling(win)[col].mean()
            x[col + '_' + str(win) + 'D' + '_std' + '_' + suffix] = x.shift(1).rolling(win)[col].std()
            x[col + '_' + str(win) + 'D' + '_min' + '_' + suffix] = x.shift(1).rolling(win)[col].min()
            x[col + '_' + str(win) + 'D' + '_max' + '_' + suffix] = x.shift(1).rolling(win)[col].max()

    return x
```

Then to apply it, as an example, I use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000000, 3)), columns=['Group','Time','Value'])
df.sort_values(by='Time', inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: GetRollingMetrics(x, ['Value'], [7,14,28], 'my_suffix'))
```

Is there a more 'Pandaic' or efficient way to do this?

Comment: "Pandaic" ... :-) Also, you want to compute these rolling stats for each column and each window?

Comment: Well, in this example I only have a single column 'Value', but I might want to compute it for multiple columns and multiple window sizes, hence cols being a list.

Comment: and 'Pandaic' does sound better - edited :)

Comment: Check out http://jonisalonen.com/2014/efficient-and-accurate-rolling-standard-deviation/. You can exploit decomposition of variance into sum of squares and squared sum: at each step cut off from tail one point and add new data to the head.

Comment: How long does your existing approach take?

Comment: I ran the above code three times and got an average of 5.5 seconds - but I am on a fairly (unusually?) powerful server. I'll give your answer a shot and see how it runs

Answer (score 0):

I refactored  your function to use `agg()`, so we can prepare all the data for each window in one shot:

```
def GetRollingMetrics(x, cols, windows, suffix):
    for win in windows:
        aggs = {col: ['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max'] for col in cols}
        df = x.shift(1).rolling(win).agg(aggs)
        # the real work is done, just copy the columns into x
        for col in cols:
            prefix = col + '_' + str(win) + 'D'
            for stat in ('mean', 'std', 'min', 'max'):
                x['_'.join((prefix, stat, suffix))] = df[col][stat]
    return x
```

It is faster if you have multiple columns.  If you have only one column, it doesn't seem to be much faster.  There's definitely room to improve in the `for stat` loop--that copying takes about half the time.  Probably you could do a rename instead, and maybe concatenate the results later?

If you're desperate to speed this up a lot more, you should consider Numba, which will let you implement one-pass min/max/sum that you can then use for all your rolling calculations.  I've done that before and you can do all four calculations in not much more time than it currently takes you to do one (because the expensive part is loading the data into cache).